# How Spring Boot 2.2.0 accept Date params in RequestBody?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to post a date in request body. Date's format is like `2019-11-11T21:21:21`. 
Sample goes below:

```java
@PostMapping("/test")
    public String test(@RequestBody User user) {
        log.info("user is = {}", user).
        return "hello";
    }
```

```java
public class User {
    private String username;
    private String password;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss")
    private Date regTime;
    // getters and setters ...
}
```

How ever, regTime of the user is always null.

How Can I post a Date `params` in `@RequestBody`?

Comment: can you please add how you are making the request.

Comment: would u please update your question with requested payload json.

Answer (score 0):

If your request payload looks like below it should work properly. (And if your getters and setters implemented by IDE, I mean if there isn't any mistake. Or better to use `lombok`) Please check below example:

```
{
    "username": "TestUser",
    "password": "123",
    "regTime" : "2019-11-11T21:21:21"
}
```